# cmake JSON cannot parse string containing ";" character

Tags: json, cmake

Minimal example (the `JSON` string command was introduced in 3.19.0):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION "3.19.0")

set(JSON1 "{ \"message\": \"hello world\" }")
set(JSON2 "{ \"message\": \"hello;world\" }")#';' inside string

string(JSON message1 GET ${JSON1} "message")#ok
string(JSON message2 GET ${JSON2} "message")#json parse error

project("blabla")
```

The `JSON2` object at key `message` is the string `hello;world`, which contains the `;` character. For some reason it makes cmake fail parsing it.

The `JSON1` object simply has a space instead of `;` and is parsed correctly.

Is this a bug in cmake or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unquoted variable expansion are split on `;`. See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#unquoted-argument . Quote them.

```
string(JSON message2 GET "${JSON2}" "message")
```